# DBPedia-France (fr.dpbedia.org/sparql) query giving different result from a call to another

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm calling on http://fr.dbpedia.org/sparql
 the following SPARQL query:

```
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select distinct ?lcs  where {

   {
     ?lcs ^(rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf*)   <http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Honoré_Daumier> , 
                                         <http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Auguste_Rodin>;
        a owl:Class .
        filter not exists {
           ?llcs ^(rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf*)  <http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Honoré_Daumier> , 
                                               <http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Auguste_Rodin>;
           a owl:Class ;
           rdfs:subClassOf+ ?lcs .
        }
   }
 }
```

On some call I've http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person as result, on others call I'm getting http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person and http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent and with others the previous answers plus http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing

without nothing to know that a response isn't complete. How can I use the result, if it is a little randomized

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/dbpedia-usage-report-as-of-2018-01-01-8cae1b81ca71) may provide the clues you need. Please also note that it's important to distinguish between the language-based chapter servers like fr.dbpedia.org, and the primary (English) DBpedia.org, not least because the former is currently running Virtuoso Open Source Edition 07.20.3214 built Jul 17 2015, vs the latter which is currently running Enterprise Edition 07.20.3230 built Dec 18 2018. Differences between versions can be significant (though probably not in this specific case)!

Comment: @TallTed To be honest, I never understood why the people do not update. It doesn't take that much time. The same holds for Italian DBpedia (you know this, there have been some questions here asking why some features of SPARQL do not work although they do in recent versions)

Comment: Ok, I found another issue with the French DBpedia. The schema is loaded into the graph `http://dbpedia.org` and the instance data is in `http://fr.dbpedia.org` - unfortunately, the default graph is **not** configured to be the union of both...weird. The working query needs to define the union graph explicitely and it works: `select distinct ?lcs  
from <http://fr.dbpedia.org> 
from <http://dbpedia.org> where ...`

Comment: @AKSW Thank's, it seems to work, but I need clarification. You obtain the result for the fusion of <http://dbpedia.org> and <http://fr.dbpedia.org> which could be different from just <http://dbpedia.org>. Is the graph <http://dbpedia.org> only the ontology or the full dbpedia? (and it doesn't explain why a given query gives different results from call to call)

Comment: @TallTed I see nothing useful in your article to understand the problem. The response header of a faulty response is {HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 06 Feb 2019 07:51:30 GMT
Server: Virtuoso/07.20.3214 (Linux) x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 186
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Cache: MISS from proxy.enst.fr
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from proxy.enst.fr:3128
Via: 1.1 proxy1.enst.fr (squid)
Connection: keep-alive}

Comment: I'm sorry; I misunderstood part of your question on first read. You're right that the article I linked does not address this. I believe that @AKSW has correctly diagnosed the "split graph" issue as part of the cause (though there are more nuances than he describes). I believe that some of [the numerous patches to Virtuoso](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/commits/stable/7) over the past 4 years will resolve the other things you're hitting (and I've pinged the fr.dbpedia.org admins to encourage them to apply such an update).

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for your query not working as expected is that the data the data is i) split into separate graphs and ii) not all graphs were added to the default graph.

To keep it short, the instance data is contained inside the graph `http://fr.dbpedia.org` whereas the schema triples will be accessible via `http://dbpedia.org` graph only. Sometimes, if no graph is given, then the union of some graphs is used as the default graph which will be the dataset at query time. Unfortunately, this doesn't hold for the French DBpedia endpoint, only the instance data graph will be used.

You can check this with

```
DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>
```

which is empty when using either no graph explicitly or the graph `http://fr.dbpedia.org`, but non-empty for graph `http://dbpedia.org`.

The way to define the default graph is using the keyword `FROM`. For your query, it should therefore be

```sql
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select distinct ?lcs  
from <http://fr.dbpedia.org> 
from <http://dbpedia.org> 
where {
     ?lcs ^(rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf*)   <http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Honoré_Daumier> , 
                                         <http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Auguste_Rodin>;
        a owl:Class .
        filter not exists {
           ?llcs ^(rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf*)  <http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Honoré_Daumier> , 
                                               <http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Auguste_Rodin>;
           a owl:Class ;
           rdfs:subClassOf+ ?lcs .
        }

 }
```

Note, while this seems to return the correct result, you should also consider the comment from @TallTed regarding possible differences among language chapters (e.g. English vs French Wikipedia as source), release dumps (2016 vs 2018 or even the DBpedia Live) as well as Virtuoso versions used as backend.

Comment: Your modified query seems to work. Good! But it doesn't explain how it is possible that my query gives different results from a call to the other and how to know when a result is the good one.

Comment: @user10867087 Well, basically I did or @TallTed did. Your query could never work because the schema data (aka the `rdfs:subClassOf` triples are not in the default graph used during query time). In addition, Virtuoso has a so-called anytime feature, i.e. it returns whatever it found in a given time. That your query returned only `dbo:Person` sometimes was just by accident. And there is no "good" result. The assumption should indeed be that the result is always sound and complete. Regarding the anytime feature, the HTTP header of the response should contain a hint for partial result iirc.

Comment: Last but not least, older versions of Virtuoso had some issues with property path which have been fixed in newer versions

Comment: @user10867087, AKSW -- If unspecified (i.e., if the "Default Data Set Name (Graph IRI)" box on the SPARQL query form is left blank, and if there is no FROM clause in the query, [etc.](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfdefaultgraph/)), Virtuoso treats the UNION of all its graphs as the default graph, which may lead to unexpected and/or undesired results, depending on (the content of) all the graphs loaded in that instance. That said, I believe that if fr.dbpedia.org updates their Virtuoso, the inconsistent results you've been seeing will become consistent.

Comment: @TallTed I know this, but without specifying a graph in the textbox, the graph `http://dbpedia.org` is not taken into account and this graph contains all the schema triples. You can check this via `DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>` which is empty but non-empty if I use it in the textbox or just the `FROM` keyword. So, for me something is wrongly configured or you're just right and it was changed in later versions of Virtuoso. Hopefully they'll update it